# When I write an int64 type number to the function, a different number is returned

Tags: python, go, ctypes, cpython

I converted the golang code to c code and called it from python. but when the function should return a number close to the number I wrote inside, it returns a very different number.

main.py

```
import ctypes

library = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./maintain.so')
hello_world = library.helloWorld
numb = 5000000000
n = ctypes.c_int64(numb)
x = hello_world(n)
print(x)
```

returning number: 705032703

golang code that I converted to c code

main.go

```
package main

import "C"

func helloWorld(x int64) int64 {
    s := int64(1)
    for i := int64(1); i < x; i++ {
        s = i
    }
    return s
 }
```

Comment: what number is this "very different number"?

Comment: I thought I'd written it right now I'm editing it again.

Comment: Where's your Python implementation of `hello_world`?

Comment: You have to declare `hello world.restype = c_int64` Or the return type is assumed to be `c_int`.

Comment: 5000000000 is greater than the max int limit also it's greater than the max unsigned integer limit too. Can you try with long etc

Comment: Same thing (duplicate) as [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making the mistake 99% of new `ctypes` users: not declaring the argument types and return type of the function used.  `ctypes` assumes `c_int` for scalars and `c_void_p` for pointers on arguments and `c_int` for return type unless told otherwise.  If you define them, you don't have to wrap every parameter in the type you want to pass, because `ctypes` will already know.

I'm not set up for Go, but here's a simple C implementation of the function with a 64-bit argument and return type:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API int64_t helloWorld(int64_t x) {
        return x + 1;
}
```

The Python code to call it:

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.helloWorld.argtypes = ct.c_int64,  # sequence of argument types
dll.helloWorld.restype = ct.c_int64    # return type

# Note you don't have to wrap the argument, e.g. c_int64(5000000000).
print(dll.helloWorld(5_000_000_000))
```

Output:

```
5000000001
```